# Repeater inside Group and the both are inside Group ACF Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm working on **ACF** Plugin in Wordpress and I have this HTML Code that split into 3 parts.
the first part is the **parent Group** inside this parent Group has also **child group** and inside **child Group** has **repeater**.
I tried to solve it like this one [[4]](https://allisontarr.com/2017/12/01/acf-repeater-within-group/)
but it didn't work. These some images to explain more

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrBue.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66eMB.png)

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmUqe.png)

```
<!--The Parent Group (section2_technology)-->
<div class="section2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="right">
      <div class="frame">
        <!-- The (qoute) text -->
        We use modern, proven technologies and approaches that allow us to effectively extend and scale our products.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
      <div class="top">
        <hr>
        <span>MOBILE</span>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <!-- The Child Group class='mobile' -->
      <div class="bottom" id="mobile">
        <div data-aos="flip-up">
          <div class="slide-down frame1">
            <div class="main-hover">
              <div class="mobile">
                IOS
              </div>
              <div class="split"></div>
              <div class="content-div">
                <div class="slide-down__top">
                  <!-- The Repeater class='type' -->
                  <div class="type">
                    <img src="" alt="" class="mobileicons-img">
                    <div class="name"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div data-aos="flip-down" data-aos-delay="200">
          <div class="slide-down">
            <div class="main-hover">
              <div class="mobile">
                ANDROID
              </div>
              <div class="split"></div>
              <div class="content-div">
                <div class="slide-down__top">
                  <!-- This is the repeater class='type' -->
                  <div class="type">
                    <img src="" alt="" class="mobileicons-img">
                    <div class="name">Java</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP should look something like this:

```
<?php if ( have_rows('parent-group') ): ?>
    <!-- html before -->
    <?php while ( have_rows('parent-group') ) : the_row(); ?>

        <?php if ( have_rows('child-group') ): ?>
            <!-- html before -->
            <?php while ( have_rows('child-group') ) : the_row(); ?>

                <?php if ( have_rows('repeater') ): ?>
                    <!-- html before -->
                    <?php while ( have_rows('repeater') ) : the_row(); ?>

                        <!-- item contents -->
                        <?php the_sub_field("image") ?>
                        <?php the_sub_field("title") ?>
                        <!-- item contents -->

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <!-- html after -->
                <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!-- html after -->
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- html after -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Remember that have_rows() defaults to the current post.

To get the rows from a diffrent post use: have_rows('key', $postID);

Or if you use the options page: have_rows('key', "options");